# Google Container Registry unexpected HTTP status: 504 Gateway Time-out

Tags: docker, google-container-registry

I made a 160GB Docker image of the Bitcoin blockchain and tried pushing it from my Google Compute Engine VM in `us-west1-b` to Google Container Registry (gcr.io).  After many hours, the status bar shows the layer has been transmitted but the message
`unexpected HTTP status: 504 Gateway Time-out` is shown.  When I browse Google Container Registry, I do not see my image.  I have successfully pushed 20+GB images from the same VM.  Is there a timeout setting I can change or is this on the Google side of the push?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably hitting the 2 hours limit on requests to Google Container Registry.

GCR Quotas & Limits: https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/quotas

Each layer of the Docker image is uploaded with a single request. You could try breaking up the image in more layers.